# What is the Basin-Hopping Metropolis Temperature?

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize

I am setting up to use SciPy's [basin-hopping](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.basinhopping.html#scipy.optimize.basinhopping) global optimizer. Its documentation for parameter `T` states

> **T: *float, optional***
>
> The “temperature” parameter for the accept or reject criterion. Higher “temperatures” mean that larger jumps in function value will be accepted. For best results `T` should be comparable to the separation (in function value) between local minima.

When it says "function value", does that mean the expected return value of the cost function `func`? Or the value passed to it? Or something else?

I read the source, and I see where `T` is passed to the Metropolis acceptance criterion, but I do not understand how it is used when converted to "beta".

Comment: Without checking i would guess: yes, the result of `func`. `the value passed to it` does not make much sense to me, especially as it's not necessarily scalar. See also [this code-part](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.5.1/scipy/optimize/_basinhopping.py#L490) (which has another wording)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm unfamiliar with the algorithm, but if you keep reading the documentation on the link you posted you'll find this:

> Choosing T: The parameter T is the “temperature” used in the Metropolis criterion. Basinhopping steps are always accepted if `func(xnew) < func(xold)`. Otherwise, they are accepted with probability:`exp( -(func(xnew) - func(xold)) / T )`. So, for best results, T should to be comparable to the typical difference (in function values) between local minima. (The height of “walls” between local minima is irrelevant.)

So I believe T should take on the value of the function which you are trying to optimize, `func`. This makes sense if you look at that probability expression -- you'd be comparing a difference in function values to what is meant to be a type of "upper bound" for the step. For example, if one local minima is `func = 10` and another is `func = 14`, you might consider `T = 4` to be an appropriate value.